# How can I add it delete Node First and delete Node Last

Tags: java

How can I add it and delete Node First and delete Node Last in a double-link list
Just want to add delete Node First and delete Node Last. I did not know how to add it in your programming, but I want to help it solve it

i have 3 class

class node  .
class doublyLinkedListMain  .
class doublyLinkedList  .

I want to add special programming in class doublyLinkedList this one delete Node First and delete Node Last

```
class doublyLinkedList
{
Node head;
public void push(int newdata) 
{ 
Node NewNode = new Node(newdata);
NewNode.next = head;   
NewNode.prev = null; 
if (head != null) head.prev = NewNode; 
head = NewNode; 
} 
public void insertAfter(Node PrevNode, int newdata) 
{ 
if (PrevNode == null)
  { 
   System.out.println("The given previous node cannot be null"); 
   return; 
  } 
Node NewNode = new Node(newdata); 
NewNode.next = PrevNode.next; 
PrevNode.next = NewNode;  
NewNode.prev = PrevNode; 
 if (NewNode.next != null) 
   NewNode.next.prev = NewNode;
} 
public void append(int newdata)
{ 
Node NewNode = new Node(newdata); 
Node last = head;
NewNode.next = null; 
 
if (head == null) 
   { 
   NewNode.prev = null; 
   head = NewNode; 
   return; 
   }
while (last.next != null) last = last.next;   
last.next = NewNode; 
NewNode.prev = last; 
return; 
} 

void insertBefore(Node NextNode, int newdata)
{   
if  (NextNode == null)
   {
    System.out.println("the given next node cannot be NULL");
    return;
   }
Node NewNode = new Node(newdata); 
NewNode.data = newdata; 
NewNode.prev = NextNode.prev; 
NextNode.prev = NewNode;  
NewNode.next = NextNode;  

if (NewNode.prev != null)
    NewNode.prev.next = NewNode;

else head = NewNode; 
}

void deleteNode( Node del)
{
if (head == null || del == null) return;
if (head == del) head = head.next;
if (del.next != null) del.next.prev = del.prev;
if (del.prev != null) del.prev.next = del.next;
return;
}
void printList() 
{
Node n = head;
while (n != null) 
  { 
   System.out.print(n.data+" "); 
   n = n.next; 
  }
  System.out.print(" \n ") ;
} 
}
```

Comment: Do yourself and everybody else looking at your code a favor and indent it properly. Follow naming conventions (classes are CamelCase, function names start with lower case letters). It's much easier to read that way. That said, you already have a method for deleting a node. Why not just call these on the first or last node, respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, but you have different mistakes in your code. Firstly, for a list you need two or three pointers as attribute in your List class (`Node head /* begin */, tail /* end */, current /* yes, the current element on which you have access */` - I have learned it with a current pointer but depending on your implementation you can do it without it too). Because of that, you must change some of your code. For example, you need a hasAccess() : boolean method, if you use a `current` pointer, which `return current != null` and your methods must consider and use `tail`. Furthermore, you should add a method `isEmpty()`:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return head == null;
}
```

This method checks if the list is empty. In the case, that the list is empty (the method returns `true`), you cannot do some things, but you had seen that yet. But, because of the new pointer tail, you have its much easier to delete the last Node (see below).

Please, change all your attributes to `private` and code a getter and a setter for each of them. For example in the class Node for the attribute next:

```
private Node next;
// other code...
public Node getNext() {
        return next;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}
```

I have solved the problem with "delete Node First and delete Node Last" in the following way:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {
    private Node head; // begin
    private Node tail; // end

    public void deleteFirstElement() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            head = head.getNext();
        }
    }

    public void deleteLastElement() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            tail = tail.getPrev();
        }
    }
// other code
}
```

Of course, you have to proof your other code, if it works. I hope that I could help you.

Comment: i have Many mistakes

Comment: I did not understand you

Comment: i have 3 class main + node + class

Comment: Yes, you have 3 classes, but you only posted the doublyLinkedList class. At what point did I lose you, @jumanjl?